# PHP Conditional Assign - Interfaces

Tags: php, types, interface

Lets say I create and interface

```
interface IMyInterface {

    function abstractMethod();

}

class MyClass implements IMyInterface {

    function abstractMethod() {
        //code
    }

}

class OtherClass {

    private $IMyInterfaceObj;

    function __construct($obj) {
        $this->IMyInterfaceObj = $obj;
    }

}
```

What can I do to make sure that the object assigned to $IMyInterfaceObj is an Object that actually implements the interface, since PHP is loosely typed. Should I check the type???

Comment: Should you need to type check objects in a slightly more dynamic way, you can also use the [instanceof](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) operator. This is usually less "pretty" than type checking in the method signature though. I'd recommend going for the accepted answer below in most cases. However `instanceof` does have it's uses in things like an abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would type hint it in the constructor. You cannot do this for basic types such as integers or strings, although you can for arrays with `array`. The only value you can use to make a parameter an optional one is to use `null`.

```
class OtherClass {

    private $IMyInterfaceObj;

    function __construct(IMyInterface $obj) {
        $this->IMyInterfaceObj = $obj;
    }

}
```

Thoroughly reading the documentation on [interfaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and [type hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) should clear anything else up on the subject.